# Wrapping and columns with flexbox (possible to realize?)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just started to work and play around with flexbox. Now I have a screendesign which I wanted to realize with flexbox.

It should have two coloumns within the desktop view and just one on mobile devices. On the desktop view a few boxes should be in the right column and the other ones in the main. [I uploaded an image, which should describe it even better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd4RI.png)

On mobile devices B should be under A, but this will be no problem for me.

I just played around with flexbox to get the elements wrapped after the boxes B and D, but right now it doesn't worked for me.

So now I have the question, if it's possible in general or do I have to work with grids, or similar? If yes, can you give me a hint for the solution?

I played around with the following code:

```
#container-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container-flex {
    background-color: #CBCBCB;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.a {
    flex: 2 0 auto;

}

.b {
    flex: 2 0 auto;
}

.c {
    flex: 4 0 auto;
}

<div id="container-main">
  <div class="container-flex a">
  </div>
</div>
```

Regards,
Markus

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I tried it, of course, but it didn't work for me right now, so I just wanted to ask, if it is possible or not. I just edited the post with my test code

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a Demo of what you have tried. There really istn't enough HTML or CSS there to see what the issue is. Also some indication of what the layout should be as "one column"...is there a set order you want to maintain?

Comment: Here is the demo: http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/yYxLpX

There is just no special order. The second element (B) in den screenshot should be next to A. On desktop C should be under A and on mobile devices just B.